# "error: no matching function for call to ..."

Tags: c++, class

I am following the instruction of [this repository](https://github.com/AdaCompNUS/despot/blob/API_redesign/examples/cpp_models/) with many given examples to build a POMDP model and use their solver for my problem.

Here is my code:

```
Belief* StarMazeProblem::Tau(const Belief* belief, ACT_TYPE action,
    OBS_TYPE obs) const {
       
    static vector<double> probs = vector<double>(NumStates());

    const vector<State*>& particles =
        static_cast<const ParticleBelief*>(belief)->particles();
  //********************

    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < particles.size(); i++) {
        
        SimpleState* state = static_cast<SimpleState*>(particles[i]);

        const vector<State>& distribution = transition_probabilities_[GetIndex(
            state)][action];

        for (int j = 0; j < distribution.size(); j++) {
            const State& next = distribution[j];

            double p = state->weight * next.weight*ObsProb(obs, next.state_id, action);
            probs[next.state_id] += p;
            sum += p;
        }
    }
  //******************
    vector<State*> new_particles;
    for (int i = 0; i < NumStates(); i++) {
        if (probs[i] > 0) {
            State* new_particle = Copy(states_[i]);
            new_particle->weight = probs[i] / sum;
            new_particles.push_back(new_particle);
            probs[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    return new ParticleBelief(new_particles, this, NULL, false);
}
```

my code is similar to [this example (line 432)](https://github.com/AdaCompNUS/despot/blob/API_redesign/examples/cpp_models/adventurer/src/adventurer.cpp). In the `starmaze.h`, function `ObsProb` is given as

```
class StarMazeProblem : public DSPOMDP {
private:
        std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<State> > > transition_probabilities_; 


public:
      StarMazeProblem();

      virtual double ObsProb(OBS_TYPE obs, const State& state, ACT_TYPE action) const;
}
```

The error message is

```
src/starmaze.cpp:317:80: error: no matching function for call to 'despot::StarMazeProblem::ObsProb(despot::OBS_TYPE&, const int&, despot::ACT_TYPE&) const'
       double p = state->weight * next.weight*ObsProb(obs, next.state_id, action);
                                                                                ^
src/starmaze.cpp:206:8: note: candidate: virtual double despot::StarMazeProblem::ObsProb(despot::OBS_TYPE, const despot::State&, despot::ACT_TYPE) const
 double StarMazeProblem::ObsProb(OBS_TYPE obs, const State& state,
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/starmaze.cpp:206:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'const int' to 'const despot::State&'
src/starmaze.cpp: In constructor 'despot::StarMazeBelief::StarMazeBelief(std::vector<despot::State*>, const despot::DSPOMDP*, despot::Belief*)':
```

Any suggestion how I can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the second note the compiler shows, you're trying to pass an int value (the `state_id`) to a parameter that wants a `const despot::State &`.

Assuming that the state ID belongs to the state you want to pass, you already have it in `next`. Rather than passing `next.state_id`, just pass `next`:

```
double p = state->weight * next.weight*ObsProb(obs, next, action);
//                                                  ^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Your call is:

```
ObsProb(obs, next.state_id, action)
```

The signature is:

```
virtual double ObsProb(OBS_TYPE obs, const State& state, ACT_TYPE action) const;
```

The error is:

```
no known conversion for argument 2 from 'const int' to 'const despot::State&'
```

So your call should be:

```
ObsProb(obs, next, action)
```